# Armstrong Number with Limit

Tags: java

I want to find the Armstrong numbers with input limit.The given program did not give number 153 as Armstrong number. Thanks in advance!

```
public class DisplayAmstrong {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int r=0,i=0,n=0,a=0,b=0;
    System.out.println("Enter the Limit:");
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    int limit=ob.nextInt();
    if(limit<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Negative number!Enter proper value!");
    }
    if(limit==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter greater than zero value!");
    }
    if(limit>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<limit;i++)
        {
             b=i;
             n=b;
             while(n!=0)
             {

               r=r-r+n%10;
               a=a+(r*r*r);
               n=n/10;

             }
               if(a==b)
               {
                     System.out.println(a);
               }

        }
        System.out.println("Limit finished!");

    }
}
}
```

The Output is:

Enter the Limit:

200

1

Limit finished!

Comment: Umm... 153 **isn't** an Armstrong number. 135 is. 1 + 9 + 125.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder : 1 + 27 + 125 in fact. So, yes, it's an Armstrong number ;)

Comment: @Stephin_Joseph What's `r=r-r+n%10;` this?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder That's pretty strange, yup. r-r = 0. Even my IDE says it's strange!

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder its a mistake,no need r-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the Limit:");
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    int limit = ob.nextInt();
    if (limit < 0) {
        System.out.println("Negative number! Enter proper value!");
    } else if (limit == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than zero!");
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            int number = i;
            while (number != 0) {   // While loop to review each digit of the number
                int digit = number - (number / 10) * 10;    // Capturing the last digit
                sum += digit * digit * digit;               // Adding digit^3
                number = number / 10;                       // Dividing number to get the next digit
            }
            if (sum == i) {     // i is an Armstrong number
                System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Limit finished!");
    }
}
```

Basically, you review each digit of your number, and you sum digit^3 to each other digit^3.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reset your variable a to 0 when you start your for loop ;)

By the way, you might want to take longer variable names, so it's easier for other people who read you (including future you) which variable corresponds to what.

Also, you can shrink your tests for the limit thingy at the start: you want a positive number, so it has to be greater than 0. Aka not inferior or equal to 0

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

add `a = 0;` before while loop. You need to reset the value of `a` for every `i`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain what was happening there?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<limit;i++)
    {
         b=i;
         n=b;
         while(n!=0)
         {

           r=r-r+n%10; // And why 'r - r'?
           a=a+(r*r*r);
           n=n/10;

         }
         if(a==b)
         {
             System.out.println(a);
         }
         a = 0;

    }
```

Comment: No need for r-r,its just a mistake from my previous program